# What does "Borel space", unqualified, refer to?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

For examples of use, Google "in Borel space", with the quotes. (Although, at the moment, I'm getting this very question as the top result.)

I'm thinking it means either ℝ equipped with its Borel σ-algebra, or to Borel spaces in general (that is, topological spaces with a σ-algebra generated through complements and countable unions of open sets). I've been given to understand that many Borel spaces are isomorphic to each other, but not in what sense they're isomorphic.

Comment: Every two uncountable separable metric spaces whose metric is complete are Borel isomorphic. Namely, there is a bijection between them which maps the Borel sets of the one exactly to the Borel sets of the other. In particular, it's a Borel measurable isomorphism as far as the $\sigma$-algebras go.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, thanks. So any two Borel-isomorphic spaces are essentially the same so far as their σ-algebras are concerned.

Comment: George Mackey used the term *Borel space* instead of measurable space and *Borel structure* instead of $\sigma$-algebra. There are a number of authors following this terminology.

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space